# How to connect to xl2tp on linux?

Tags: ubuntu, vpn, l2tp

I have install an l2tp server named [xl2tp](http://www.xelerance.com/services/software/xl2tpd/), I want to know if there is any l2tp client for linux which can connect the server?

Answer (score 1):

The openswan ipsec tools can be used for this purpose. You can see how to do it [here](http://www.jacco2.dds.nl/networking/linux-l2tp.html).